# How can I make sure something is only done once in entire application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

Well I guess the question speaks for itself. Here is some code (test.cs) makes it clearer:

```
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string sessieVak = reader["vak"].ToString();
            if (variable == "cool")
            {
                //This part can only happen once in the entire application 
                HttpContext.Current.Session[sessieVak] = true;
            }
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session[sessieVak] != null)
            {
                str.Append("<li><a href = vak.aspx?id=" + reader["kdv_ID"] + " />" + reader["vak"] + "</a></li>");
            }
        }
```

I hope you guys can help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: after executing the line, set the `variable` to something not equal to `cool`.

Comment: What does "once in the entire application" even mean?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Thanks that I didn't see that myself.

Comment: Further to what @ShivanRaptor has suggested, I'd recommend you use a bool instead of a string if this is all it's used for.

Comment: @AntP When they login

Comment: You may think "happen once" is a clear description, but it's far from clear to me - once during a particular user's session? Once for the entire history of the universe? Something in between (once per app-domain recycle?)

Comment: @Daan Oh right well that clears it up then (not really).

Comment: You could ask the users to only press the button once?

Comment: Sorry guys im not very good at plain english.

Comment: It's also not really clear what you're trying to prevent. Setting `HttpContext.Current.Session[sessieVak] = true;`, if `Session[sessieVak]` was already `true` is a mostly pointless operation but it happening multiple times should be unnoticeable for any other piece of code - whether it was set once or multiple times.

Comment: OP what's 'variable'? Where is it declared? Under what circumstances would it NOT equal "cool"?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `static bool` as a flag:

```
static bool done = false;    

if (variable == "cool" && done == false)
{
    //This part can only happen once in the entire application 
    HttpContext.Current.Session[sessieVak] = true;
    done = true;
}
```

Comment: Your comment's not necessarily true. If a new object is created (containing this code), done will be set to false, thus the session variable will be assigned the 'true' value again.

Comment: @DeeMac fair point, not sure if it justifies a downvote though

Comment: @Paddyd The question is impossible to answer because it is so unclear what the problem is; the appropriate response to a vague question is not to post a vague answer, it is to require clarification. Like the question, this answer is meaningless without context. Saying "set a variable somewhere, dunno where, it depends on what you're trying to do," doesn't really have any value.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes, i had just modified it to static ;)

Comment: @AntP The OP asked how he could get a section of the code to execute only once. It sounded pretty straight forward to me

Comment: Only once in that loop? In that user session? In that request context? In that application pool cycle? In the entire period that the application exists in a production environment? It's not *at all* clear what the question is and it's equally not at all clear what question you're answering, because you have posted a vague "catch-all" answer to a vague question that has no clear answer without more context.